# Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement Iconics library and I'm getting this error.

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0-rc02] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0-rc02] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-58:19 to override.
```

Here is my dependencies:

```
final String version= '28.0.0-rc02'
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$version"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$version"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$version"
    implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3"
    implementation "com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.3.0"
    implementation "com.github.daniel-stoneuk:material-about-library:2.3.0"
    implementation "com.mikepenz:iconics-core:3.1.0-rc02"
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:community-material-typeface:2.7.94.1@aar'
}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add below two lines in Gradle.Properties

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

I had the same problem, 
or follow below link

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: This is not the correct solution. Yes, it might correct the issue but the assumption that the OP (or anyone seeing similar issues) wants to (or is able to) convers their project to AndroidX would be an incorrect assumption in my opinion.

I would prefer to see a solution that does not require the upgrade to AndroidX which can potentially bring significantly more issues.

Comment: @Ken Which could be the solution do you refer to?

Comment: I refer to the solution telling the OP to migrate to AndroidX.  I see this reply quite often now but I don't feel that a correct answer to an app using the older support libraries should need to be ported to AndroidX; this is no small change in most cases I've run across.  In my opinion the OP was asking how to solve the issue using support libraries and in that case I don't feel that suggesting changing the whole app to use AndroidX is a solution

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem，here's my answer:

In your Manifest.xml add a few lines of code.

```xml
<application
        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
        android:appComponentFactory="Any character"
        ......
        >
```